# How can I send the id of an element as a name using POST request?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I've used `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Since for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the body of the HTTP message sent to the server is essentially one giant query string -- name/value pairs are separated by the ampersand (&), and names are separated from values by the equals symbol (=). An example of this would be: `MyVariableOne=ValueOne&MyVariableTwo=ValueTwo` but I want to send the id as a variable, not as a value. How can I send id as a variable? Following is my program: Thanks in Advance.

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script>
function fun1(element) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "/prc", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
    xhttp.send(element.id);
    //alert("ID":element.id);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="fun1(this)" id="img1">IMAGE</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a FormData object, add your data to that object and send that object. Refer to this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("MyVariableOne", "ValueOne");
formData.append("id", 123456);

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "/prc", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
xhttp.send(formData);
```

Comment: I tried using this. Unfortunately, it's not working.

Comment: Does it give you any error? Provide more information in question regarding your attempt with FormData as well.

Comment: ```
<HTML>
<head>
<script>
function fun1(element) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("id", element.id);
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "/prc", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
    xhttp.send(formData);
    //alert("ID":element.id);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="fun1(this)" id="img1">IMAGE</button>
</body>
</html>

```

Comment: Could you please point out, if I've made any mistakes?

Comment: You would have to provide what error you're getting in console.

Comment: Error getting on the console - Cross-Origin Request Blocked (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

Comment: Also- Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined

Comment: You are using "/prc" in xhttp.open() which might not be a working url. You'll have to provide a proper URL or file to handle this request. Learn more about it here https://javascript.info/xmlhttprequest. For CORS you can use "Allow CORS" extensions which are available for browsers for testing purposes.